# Issue in Loading data from Movielens into pig

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

I'm trying to load some data into Pig:

Record:

```
11::American President, The (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance

12::Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995)::Comedy|Horror
```

Script Used:

```
loadMoviesDs = LOAD '/Users/Prateek/Downloads/ml-10M100K/movies.dat' 
               USING PigStorage(':') 
               AS (Movieid:long, dummy1, Title:chararray, dummy2, Genere:chararray);
```

Output

```
 11,,American President, The (1995),,Comedy|Drama|Romance
 12,,Dracula,, Dead and Loving It (1995)
```

How to tackle the colon(:) after Dracula.-?

due to the colon, the second column is getting split into 2 columns and since we have in total of 3 columns, the last column of movieid 12 `comedy|horror` doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`.

Following is the piece of code, which achieves this:

```
A = LOAD '/Users/Prateek/Downloads/ml-10M100K/movies.dat' 
               AS (f1:chrarray); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(f1, '(.*)::(.*)::(.*)');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0 AS (MovieID:long), $1 AS (Title:chararray), $2 AS (Genre:chararray);
DUMP D;
```

I got the following output (which is a tuple). ":" after "Dracula" is intact.

```
(11,American President, The (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance)
(12,Dracula: Dead and Loving It (1995),Comedy|Horror)
```

Comment: D = FOREACH B GENERATE $0, $1, $2;                                                                dump D                                                                                                                                         error - Out of bound access. Trying to access non-existent column: 1. Schema org.apache.pig.builtin.regex_extract_all_f1_225:tuple() has 1 column(s).                                                                                                                SO basically I want three columns moved, title , genre         How to get the o/p in 3 columns?